# "let" causing a dead lock on variables in console

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

[image: "let" in console]
As shown above, a variable got locked in console after declared with error. Neither can I assign nor re-declare it.

However, everything works just fine when using "var". In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/3624706), @ThinkingStiff explained it:

> **Redeclaration**:
>   Assuming strict mode, var will let you re-declare the same variable in the same scope. On the other hand, let will not.

So I wonder what feature of "let" produces this lock.

*My guess*: "let" first creates a temporal dead zone then assigns it with the statement all in **one** operation(one continuous series). Error occurred in the assignment statement didn't break the dead zone.

ps. I'm using Chrome 71.

Comment: The `.getElementById()` function requires a string argument; what could it possibly mean to call it without one?

Comment: Also the console is a weird environment that's useful for debugging but not really the same as an actual block of JavaScript imported into a web page.

Comment: @Pointy I imagine it's just there as an example of when the right-hand side of the `=` throws an error, could substitute it with anything else that throws and the same behavior will be seen

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok that's certainly possible, but again the console is a weird place to test JavaScript semantics because it's not designed to do that.

Comment: Also the Firefox console does not behave that way. After a failed `let` initialization, the symbol is still declared.